# aspnetcore web project import another project's controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

#### two project's csproj and version :

AspNetCore Web Project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Controller\Controller.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Controller Project

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

#### Controller Project Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Hello S.O");
    }
}
```

#### Question

if run AspNetCore Web Project it'll get `HTTP ERROR 404`,how do i reference it successfully?

Comment: I had same issue when I hosted app via TestHost, workaround was - manually adding assembly containing controllers in `Startup.cs`  `service.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);`

Comment: @khoroshevj you can answer below it's the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue when I hosted app via TestHost, workaround was - manually adding assembly containing controllers in Startup.cs.

```
service.AddMvc()
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
```

Comment: That's a good answer but it is strange because it is working for me without adding this line. What could be the reason?

Comment: New hosting model could be the problem maker in this case, but I'm not sure

Comment: @ITWeiHan, adding nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC` in your TestWeb.Infrastructure project instead of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` makes it work without the line given in the above answer. I had used AspNetCore.MVC at my end when I tried, hence it worked.

Comment: @Priyank Panchal yes ! it's answer without edit code. you can change below your answer .

Comment: According to @PriyankPanchal answer `InProcess` has nothing to do with it. edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess your project reference in AspNetCore.csproj is pointing to a wrong path.

Please try to change

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ControllerProject\Controller.csproj" />
```

to

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Controller\Controller.csproj" />
```

**EDIT**

Using the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC` instead of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` should solve the issue without the need to edit the `startup.cs` file. But I would personally prefer the solution given by @khoroshevj

Comment: sorry,I'm sorry that I made a mistake,it fixed the question. it's not name's question