# Class project why need add 『Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC』 ProjectReference in aspnetcore2.2 if already included 『Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0』

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

[c# - aspnetcore web project import another project's controller - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175398/aspnetcore-web-project-import-another-projects-controller)

#### two project's csproj and version :

AspNetCore Web Project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Controller\Controller.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Controller Project

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

#### Controller Project Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Hello S.O");
    }
}
```

#### Question

if run AspNetCore Web Project it'll get `HTTP ERROR 404`.

I need to add `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC"/>` in cspoj 
to run successfully.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But Isn't [NuGet | Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.0) already included `Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC`,Why i need to add again?

[image]

Comment: In your AspNetCore project you reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` while in your controller project you reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. Maybe this makes a difference somehow?

Comment: @Jay Fridge thanks , i'll check about this.